# Scrapy ImportError: no module named symp.settings

Tags: python, python-import, scrapy

Using Scrapy: 
When trying to execute the command: scrapy startproject example on my laptop: I'm running in to this error. How to fix?

```
File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
     sys.exit(execute())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
settings = get_project_settings()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 282, in setmodule
module = import_module(module)
File   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named symp.settings
```

Comment: is your project call symp by any chance? seems like scrapy can't find `settings.py` file. Can you post the tree of your project location and contents of `scrapy.cfg`?

Comment: scrapy location is /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/

Comment: and running scrapy in a folder on my desktop

Comment: could you post the contents of that folder?